# How do I split up an array and set key names

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of data like this that is passed to my controller via a form. It's being collected in a javascript function. It will always be email the name but there could be 2 sets or 100.

```
array:10 [▼
  0 => "ken@email.com"
  1 => "Ken"
  2 => "robert@email.com"
  3 => "Robert"
  4 => "robert@email.com"
  5 => "Robert"
  6 => "mike@email.com"
  7 => "Mike"
]
```

I'm currently doing this

```
$recipients = array_chunk($recipients, 2);

array:5 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
      0 => "ken@email.com"
      1 => "Ken"
  1 => array:2 [▼
      0 => "robert@email.com"
      1 => "Robert"
  2 => array:2 [▼
      0 => "robert@email.com"
      1 => "Robert"
  3 => array:2 [▼
      0 => "mike@email.com"
      1 => "Mike"
]
```

What I need though is this...

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
      email => "ken@email.com"
      name => "Ken"
  1 => array:2 [▼
      email => "robert@email.com"
      name => "Robert"
  2 => array:2 [▼
      email => "robert@email.com"
      name => "Robert"
  3 => array:2 [▼
      email => "mike@email.com"
      name => "Mike"
]
```

How? Thanks!

Comment: So if there is always email and name it will always be an even number?

Comment: Unless the API I'm querying screws up, but as far as I can tell, it's not happened yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-add the value back to the array with a key and remove its duplicate by the index.

```
   $recipients = array(
      0 => "ken@email.com",
      1 => "Ken",
      2 => "robert@email.com",
      3 => "Robert",
      4 => "robert@email.com",
      5 => "Robert",
      6 => "mike@email.com",
      7 => "Mike"
    );

    $recipients = array_chunk($recipients, 2);

    for ($i=0; $i < count($recipients); $i++)
    {
        $recipients[$i]['email'] = $recipients[$i][0];
        $recipients[$i]['name'] = $recipients[$i][1];
        unset($recipients[$i][0]);
        unset($recipients[$i][1]);
    }
```

It would result in the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => ken@email.com
            [name] => Ken
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [email] => robert@email.com
            [name] => Robert
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [email] => robert@email.com
            [name] => Robert
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [email] => mike@email.com
            [name] => Mike
        )

)
```

I hope it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.

```
<?php
$array = array(
"foo" => "bar",
"bar" => "foo",
100   => -100,
-100  => 100,
);
var_dump($array);
?>
```

add to an array with custom key

```
<?php
$array= array();
$array[]='name=>bob';
var_dump($array);
```

[Array docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)